# Google drive API doesn't authorize me after clicking continue

Tags: python, google-api, drive

For the first time, I created a project using googles Oauth2 and Google Drive Api. But when I click continue, my console doesn't continue with the program. And the redirect for google just sends me to a webpage that is not found. Probably a stupid question, but is there a way to fix this?

```
http://localhost:45309/?state=eB0DGVRM8HRZJo00lhRmTxyheQUMfz&code=4/0AX4XfWik1Gd36iud8XolBUj1WR8KE6D_1t3b8O3S5XRIHkajvsQWglBB-OChfW8qNZp84w&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly
```

To add onto this:

[image]

Comment: The URL in your post is different than the one in the image; if you copy and paste the one that's in the image into a web browser, does that link work? If you click it, I'd expect that the next time you start your program you won't get that message.

Comment: @RandomDavis they are different because it redirected me to it. I did re run my program and it requires me to authorize again and just redirects me to the same localhost

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

I guess my computer had some permission disabling the hosting of localhost ports breaking googles auth system.